# How to change camera view size of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to change the displayable frame size of UIImagePickerController? I want to display camera view but not on the entire screen, but say in a 280*190  bounding box at the middle of view

Here is my `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];  

[super viewDidAppear:YES];
 }
```

I could not find a way to do that anywhere...doesnt anyone using it?

How can i use overlay class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can use a custom frame size for `UIImagePickerController`. If you want a custom sized camera view and capture size you should have a look at the `AVFoundation` classes - specifically the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, `AVCaptureDeviceInput`, and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` classes.

Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2 for more information on using this framework.

Comment: +1 Good Answer...But Making capture from UIImagePickerController is different from making capture from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer right?..I mean they will show some difference in output picture quality..Am i right?

Comment: @AshokKumar.S You should take the image from the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` (for a still image), not from the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. That's really intended for previewing what the camera will capture, not for the actual capture.